# Programming on PySpark (local) vs. Python on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Recently I've been working a lot with pySpark, so I've been getting used to it's syntax, the different APIs and the HiveContext functions. Many times when I start working on a project I'm not fully aware of what its scope will be, or the size of the input data, so sometimes I end up requiring the full power of distributed computing, while on others I end up with some scripts that will run just fine on my local machine.

My question is, is there a disadvantage to coding with pySpark as my main language as compared to regular Python/Pandas, even for just some exploratory analysis? I ask mainly because of the cognitive work of switching between languages, and the hassle of moving my code from Python to pySpark if I do en up requiring to distribute the work.

In term of libraries I know Python would have more capabilities, but on my current projects so far don't use any library not covered by Spark, so I'm mostly concerned about speed, memory and any other possible disadvantage; which would perform better on my local machine?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't see any disadvantage per se. Even with PySpark you can still use Python libraries as and when required. So I would definitely recommend you to go ahead with PySpark, considering that you would have to work with very large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. We've done most of our development in Python (primarily Pandas) and now we're moving into Spark as our environment has matured to the point that we can use it.

The biggest disadvantage I see to PySpark is when we have to perform operations across an entire DataFrame but PySpark doesn't directly support the library or method. For example, when trying to use the Lifetimes library, this is not supported by PySpark so we either have to convert the PySpark Dataframe to a Pandas Dataframe (which takes a lot of time and loses the advantage of the cluster) or convert the code to something PySpark can consume and parallelize across the PySpark DataFrame.

Comment: The other disadvantage depends on how you like to use Python - if you're an analyst, you like looking at the data every so often. This takes a lot of time on PySpark - just pulling a .take() or .show() method on PySpark can drag as the cluster pulls everything back to the edge node, where a .head() method on Pandas takes only seconds.